# FlinkKafkaConsumer watermark chart legend

Tags: apache-flink

I'm trying to understand this picture [image] from https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html#watermark-strategies-and-the-kafka-connector

- what does white rectangle with text like `N|39` in it mean?
- what does yellow rectangle with a number in it mean (with or without black boundary)?
- what does text like `W(33)` mean?
- what does dotted black lines near `W(17)` mean?
- What does the number in grey circle mean, i.e. the `(1)` or `(2)` under Source, map, or window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I interpret this diagram:

- a white rectangle with text like `N|39` indicates an event for key N with timestamp 39
- a yellow rectangle with a number in it shows the current watermark for that operator instance
- `W(33)` is a Watermark on the wire with a timestamp of 33
- the dotted black lines near `W(17)` show that `W(17)` is part of the streaming data flow
- the numbers in grey circles, i.e. the (1) or (2) under Source, map, or window indicate parallel instances

Also, the four orange cylinders are Kafka partitions. `Source(1)` and `Source(2)` are each connected to two Kafka partitions. The `FlinkKafkaConsumer` is tracking the maximum timestamp observed so far in each partition, and is emitting watermarks relative to the minimum of those per-partition maximums (after subtracting some bounded delay, in the case of a BoundedOutOfOrderness watermarking strategy).

Comment: I feel your answer could be added to the doc, which would benefit more users of flink